# Sub site with own content database

Tags: 2010, content-database

We have one site collection with many sub sites in one content database. Now we wanna "split" the content into more content databases. Is it possible to "move" the sub sites into a new content database?

Or do we have to "export" the sub sites as new site colletion? How do we can add a content database to a new site colletion?

We are working with many lookup colums and content types from the root site. Also we use webparts to show lists on subsites. If we create a new site colletion do we have to create all columns, content types and lists new?
Maybe that's a dumb question, but i read some articles and i don't get it.

Answer (score 2):

you can, where you see in central admin the content db you can add another content database! when creating a site collection you need to stop the first content db that you dont want it in and keep the other enabled... when you create the site collection it would be added to the active conetent database! than reenable the one you stopped and hay presto you have two site collections on seperate content databases ;)

more info here with diagrams:

http://blogs.technet.com/b/sharepointcomic/archive/2009/07/21/unique-content-database-per-sharepoint-site-collection.aspx

for pre existing content database that contains more than one site collection that you want to split follow this msdn tutorial on splitting content databases:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc825327(v=office.12).aspx

**Split a content database (move a site collection to a different database)**

> 1.At a command prompt on the drive where SharePoint Products and Technologies is installed, change to the following directory:
>
> %COMMONPROGRAMFILES%\Microsoft shared\Web server extensions\12\Bin
>
> 2.Type the following command, and then press ENTER: Stsadm -o enumsites -url  > .xml
>
> where url is the address of the Web application that contains the site
>   collection that you want to move, and path/file name is the name of
>   the XML file that you want to create with the site collection data.
>
> For more information, see Enumsites: Stsadm operation (Windows
>   SharePoint Services).
>
> The previous step creates an XML file that contains all of the site
>   collection URLs in the current database.
>
> 3.Open the XML file that you created in a text editing application. If there are any URLs for site collections that you do not want to move,
>   be sure to delete them from the file. The only URLs that should remain
>   in the XML file should be for the site collections that you want to
>   move.
>
> Note:   There is no need to change the site count or any of the other
>   site collection information in the file. Only the URLs are relevant to
>   this procedure.
>
> 4.Type the following command, and then press ENTER: Stsadm -o mergecontentdbs -url  -sourcedatabasename 
>   -destinationdatabasename  -operation 3 -filename
>
> where url is the address of the Web application that contains the site
>   collection that you want; sourcedatabasename is the name of the
>   database that you want to move the site collection from;
>   destinationdatabasename is the name of the database that you want to
>   move the site collection to; operation 3 is the “Read from file”
>   operation; and file name is the name of the file that contains the
>   site collection URLs that you want to move.
>
> For more information, see Mergecontentdbs: Stsadm operation (Windows
>   SharePoint Services).
>
> 5.Restart IIS by typing the following command, and then pressing ENTER: iisreset /noforce

Comment: Sorry but i don't get it. We have one site collection and we wanna split some sub sites to another content db. If we add a new site colletion we have to make all content types new for this site colletion. I tested the solution with a new site collection. We can't work with our content types or our lookup fields in the new site collection. Or am i wrong?

Comment: no that is not possible! what your refering too is  BLOB system and Archive, rbs (remote blob storage) http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mossbiz/archive/2011/07/09/sharepoint-2010-rbs-benefits-trade-offs.aspx unfortunatly content db have a 1 to 1 relation not a 1 to many! to overcome this space issue you need to look at RBS instead!

Comment: may i asky why you want to split the subsite to its own content db?

Comment: webapps can have many site collections and many content databases, the site collection can only have 1 content database, content database can have many site collections, subsites cannot be stored in seperate content databases! that is delt at sitecollection level! blob is the other solution to your problem if its space that is an issue!

Comment: We have a data archive in our site collection and we wanna save this archiv daily. So the idea was to "split" the site out of the site collection into an own content database. The documents for the archive are created daily from a workflow. So, if we add a new data archive as own site collection the workflow won't work.

Comment: unfortunatly its not possible unless you somehow change the workflow through code! otherwise its rbs that your looking for! it does what you just described!

Comment: Okay thank you for your quick and helpful advice. So i gonna check out the rbs link from above.